# The [related] tag is related to poorly tagged questions, time to burninate it

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [related](/questions/tagged/related) tag is a hodgepodge of poorly tagged questions.

- A *lot* are about "related products" in various ecommerce solutions
- Many are about SQL queries, though most people don't seem to use it as an accidental synonym for "relational"
- The rest are about "this is related to that" in general

The tag, as it is, serves little purpose.

There are only **120** tagged questions.  Time to go through them and fix'em up!

Comment: send it to tag-hell, covered in marmite and being devoured by hungry hungry hippos... then nuke it

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new word today: hodgepodge.

Comment: @Jamal hodgepodge is a great word isn't it?

Comment: @UV-D: Indeed.  I'm even more fascinated by the [synonyms and related words](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hodgepodge).

Comment: @UV-D hippos AND nuking?  But won't you hurt the hippos with the nuclear strike?  You must not be a member of PETA.

Comment: @psubsee2003 the hippos are radiation hardened and won't be harmed... PETA? naaaaah, I eat too much wildlife

Comment: Programmers for the Ethical Typing of Algorithms?

Comment: People for Eating Tasty Animals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took all of my daily downvote quota and almost all of my close votes, but [related](/questions/tagged/related) has been purged.

Comment: Don't forget to check back tomorrow and make sure it's still gone. Before then, the tag still exists such that low-rep users can still add to their questions.

Comment: You can bet it's on my list of **92** tags I keep dead every day.